# Highcharts - PieChart refreshes on click event that calls this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, onclick, setstate

I have two pie charts from highcharts, and when I click a slice from the charts, I'd like for a list of tasks to show up in a table. Here is my parent component:

```
import React, { PureComponent, useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import getTasks from './tasks';
import PieChart from './PieChart';
import TaskList from './TaskList';

export default class Main extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { 
            group1: {
                series: getGroup1()
            },
            group2: {
                series: getGroup2()
            },
            tasks: []
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        let selectedTasks = getTasks(e.point.name)
        let { tasks } = this.state;
        tasks = selectedTasks;
        this.setState({tasks});
  }

  render() {
    const {series} = this.state;
    return (
        <Grid divided='vertically'>
            <Grid.Row columns={2}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <PieChart 
                        data={this.state.group1}
                        handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <PieChart 
                    data={this.state.group2}
                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Container>
            <Grid.Row columns={1}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <TaskList 
                        tasks={this.state.tasks}
                    />
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
            </Container>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

The tasks are passed to the TaskList child component as props. However, when the pie chart is clicked to trigger the `handleClick()` function, the entire chart refreshes, I'm assuming because the entire state is updated when `setState` is called - the pie charts are also fed data from `this.state.group1` and `this.state.group2`.

What's the best way to feed the task data to the TaskList component without having the entire chart refresh when it's clicked? I assumed using `setState` would be the best way, but it looks like it is updating the entire state instead of just the `task` array.

Comment: Hi @user1893649, Could you provide us with the code of `PieChart`  component? Or reproduce the problem in some online code editor, you can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-e1ue3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this happening because your component state is updating. to solve this you need to wrap your `PieChart` component with `React.memo(pieChart)`, which will check for props changes and prevent component from re-rendering. But keep in mind how that checking props change work with JavaScript data types comparison example:

```
{}==={} //false
[]===[] //false
"hello"==="hello"//true
```

Comment: My PieChart component is a class component. Can I use React.memo() with a class component?

Comment: @user1893649 yes it can be used with class component but i suggest turning your PieChart component into Pure Component which work same as `React.memo` but its optimized more for class Component